# Is there a way to connect CKFinder to an Azure storage blob?

Tags: asp.net, azure, storage, ckfinder

I'm migrating an app from a shared hosting provider to Microsoft Azure. The CMS portion of the application uses CKFinder to manage files. After much research it seems the best way to host the shared files so all the instances can access the files is via storage blobs. Is there a way to connect CKFinder up to an Azure storage blob? I'm sure this problem has been solved, I just can't find it.

Comment: looks like CKFinder wants BaseDir to be a physical path, so could point to a Windows Azure Drive (which fronts blob storage), but that's only writable by one instance at any given time - not sure if you've gone down that path (no pun intended) yet?

Comment: I had. The one instance at a time was my deal breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKFinder uses a connector on the server side to access storage. For Microsoft Azure cloud storage, you will need a custom connector based on CKFinder for ASP.NET to bridge System.IO API calls to the Azure cloud blob API.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/achilles-software/cloudstorageprovider) to an open source cloud storage provider for ASP.NET